# How to force Conda to use gcc found at /usr/bin/gcc?

Tags: 18.04, gcc, anaconda

On Ubuntu 18.04 I run `which gcc` and the output is as expected.

```
ubuntu@USER1:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

However when I activate my `conda` environment and run `which gcc` I get:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@USER1:~$ which gcc
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/gcc
```

This location seems strange to me. I wan to use the normal system wide `gcc`.

I know this is not default behaviour as in my other Ubuntu instance when I run `which gcc` the output is correct:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@USER2:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

How can I get `conda` to use the default `gcc` as shown with `USER2`?

---

**EDIT:**

`USER1` instance: `conda 4.5.12`

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@USER1:~$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix 
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC)
```

but

```
ubuntu@USER1:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.conda.io,

> Anaconda 5.0 switched from OS-provided compiler tools to our own toolsets. This allows improved compiler capabilities, including better security and performance. This page describes how to use these tools and enable these benefits.

You will have to remove the `gcc` provided by `conda`. to do so, use `conda remove gcc_linux-64`. to verify use To confirm that a package has been removed: `conda list` Now, close the terminal and re-check

Comment: `conda --version` returns `conda 4.5.12` so I'm not sure if this is the case.